# How do I avoid having to set size of UIPopoverController manually?

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

When I present a ViewController in an popup, it resizes the view. To avoid that, I have to set the view size manually using UIPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:settingsViewSize

I have tried to override contentSizeForViewInPopover

```
-(CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{
    return self.view.frame.size;
}
```

...but to no avail.

Suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926308/uipopovercontroller-w-uinavigationcontroller-subview-contentsizeforviewinpopove

Comment: Martin, it does not seem to be the same issue.

Comment: Try to set an explicit size in `contentSizeForViewInPopover`: `return CGSizeMake(200., 200.)`.

Comment: Martin, that's what I want to avoid. I want to use IB to design my views, and not have to update code if I change the size of them. This is a huge issue, as my app is multi-language, and some views have different size depending on the language.

Comment: OK, I understand. But perhaps it helps to narrow down the problem: Does setting an explicit size work?

Comment: Setting an explicit size in the viewController contentSizeForViewInPopover works, but has the same issues as the current solution - another place to change for each language. Setting a size using return self.view.frame.size; as shown in the question does not.

Comment: Your `contentSizeForViewInPopover` method worked in my test app. Do you have a navigation controller inside the popover?

Comment: Nope, a quite vanilla view controller.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `contentSizeForViewInPopover`, what is the value of `self.view.frame` and `self.view.bounds` ?

Comment: Both are 768 x 1004, so size of the entire screen. Not what I want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16461/discussion-between-martin-r-and-anders-sewerin-johansen)

Comment: Thank you for the offer. Sorry, but kinda hard to make work for me. I am on Central European Time, and work most of the day in a Day Job where I'm not allowed web access to unapproved sites.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is called before `viewWillDisplay`, so the frames of the views haven't been set yet. There are a few things you can do though.

If you are using a `UITableViewController` a little known trick to sizing your `UIPopoverViewController` to match the height of your `UITableView` is to use the tableView's `rectForSection` method to give you the height. Use the height in your viewController's `contentSizeForViewInPopover` like this:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover 
{
    // Currently no way to obtain the width dynamically before viewWillAppear.
    CGFloat width = 200.0; 
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:lastSectionIndex];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
    return (CGSize){width, height};
}
```

Or alternately, you can manually set the `contentSizeForViewInPopopver` property in your viewController's `viewWillAppear:` method and set the popover's size when you create it.

So, in your viewController which will be in the popover, you'll have this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.size
}
```

And you'd create  your popover like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
self.currentPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
[self.currentPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds 
                                     inView:sender 
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                                   animated:YES];

// resize the popover to match what you set in vc viewDidLoad
[self.currentPopover setPopoverContentSize:vc.contentSizeForViewInPopover animated:NO];
```

Comment: contentSizeForViewInPopover is deprecated in iOS7. Try this is **viewDidAppear**: 

`self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;`